# how to change the test description of python (2.7) untitest

Tags: python, unit-testing, docstring

It seems that the unittest module has been changed a lot in Python 2.7

I have a test case:

```
class DemoTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_foo(self):
      """Test foo"""
      pass
```

The console output is:

**Test foo ... ok**

After upgrading to Python 2.7, the console output is now:

**test_foo (testcase.demotest.DemoTest)**

**Test foo ... ok**

The first line of description is useless. I want to hide it, but do not know how to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you've taken the trouble to write docstrings for your test, the extra output looks a bit redundant. Below is one way it could be suppressed; you'd need to add this to the top of your test file:

```
from unittest.runner import TextTestResult
TextTestResult.getDescription = lambda _, test: test.shortDescription()
```

Comment: I love the smell me monkey patching in the morning.

Comment: Hehe, I agree, and I wish there was a less hacky way to do this in 2.7.  I tried a few other things, but this ended up being the shortest path to producing the desired output.

Comment: Wheh I try this on python 2.7 I get "TypeError: expected a character buffer object" It can be fixed just casting to string:
`TextTestResult.getDescription = lambda _, test: str(test.shortDescription())`

Comment: Thanks! Without this adjustment, you'll get the exception above instead of any error in your test or code.

Comment: Can I store the value of description in a variable? How? And Is it possible to suppress second line Test foo ...  as well?

Comment: Yes. I could store it like this:   x= self.shortDescription()